# How can I page json results with will_paginate

Tags: ruby, json, pagination, cursor, sinatra

I am using Sinatra, Ruby and Postgres. I want to page (currently trying with will_paginate but alternative method suggestions welcome) the results.

The ruby code is:

```
get '/inplay' do 
  results = DB["select distinct(concat(c.first,' ', c.last)) as candidate, c.id as id, s.shortname as shortname from candidates c, shortmembers sm, shortlists s where sm.short_id = s.list_id and c.id = sm.candidate_id"].map do |row|
         { :id => row[:id], :candidate => row[:candidate], :shortname=>row[:shortname] }
        end
    halt 200, results.to_json  
end
```

and the jquery, in the view page, is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("script");
$('#result').html('');
$.getJSON("/inplay", function(data) {
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
$('#result').append('<tr><td style=\"background:#E3F6CE;\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"case\" class=\"case\" value=' + this["id"] + '></td><td><a href=\"/edit/' + this["id"] + '\">' + this["candidate"] + '</a></td><td>' + this["shortname"] + '</td></tr>');
          });
    });
});
```

This works fine and produces a nice table. Problem is when I include:

```
page = params.fetch "page", 1
per_page = params.fetch "per_page", 10
```

in the ruby snippet and add

```
.paginate(page.to_i, per_page.to_i)
```

it no longer works and certainly does not page.

In the view I have tried:

```
<%= will_paginate results %>
```

I have also included DB.extension(:pagination) immediately after the ruby DB call.

Questions are:

1. Is the approach wrong? The paging works well with a normal dataset but not with json results.
2. If the approach is correct where do I stick the snippet ".paginate(page.to_i.per_page.to_i)" ? I have tried chaining it after .map and after .to_json with no success.

I am stuck. All help cheerfully received.

Comment: There's a [good RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised) on endless scroll. Railscasts are really worth their subscription.

Comment: thanks but I don't think that is what I am looking for, also it's rails not Sinatra.

Comment: The described technique is applicable with any framework and language and you can easily adapt it to Sinatra.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is how to ...? Also I would like initially, at least, to see if I can make my approach work and understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: What ORM are you using? I know there are limits to what will_paginate will support (and I'm fairly certain direct DB interaction isn't supported). You might just try adding LIMIT and OFFSET to your SELECT statement to get started. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/queries-limit.html

Comment: thanks, I have given up with this approach and I am using json results paged with a jquery plugin which works fine. Thank you for your comment though.